# Отправить excel файл на печать в Python

Tags: python, excel, печать, принтер

Стоит задача: после того, как скрипт, написанный на Python формирует xlsx файл, отправить его на печать. Как можно это сделать силами Python или с помощью системных вызовов? Нашёл, что есть модуль pycups, который позволяет работать с принтером и отправлять на него файлы, но он лишь для Unix-подобных систем. Интересуют возможности для Windows и Linux (можно по отдельности для каждого).

Comment: А попробуйте так: `import os` `os.startfile('path/to/file', 'print')`

Comment: О, здорово, это работает на Windows 7) А не подскажите, будет ли команда работать в Linux?

Comment: В документации написано, что `os.startfile` доступна только для windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Windows можно использовать [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile).

Пример:

```
import os
os.startfile('path/to/file', 'print')
```